# How do I debug a Javascript class that is part of a React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, debugging

When I develop a React Component, I use the `console.log()` statement for debugging. When the component is rendered, the `console.log()` statement is printed into the console and that is all that I presently use for my debugging.

But how do I debug a javascript class? I would like to use my `console.log()` statements also in a Javascript class. But how can I do that? The problem is that the class itself does not get rendered into the DOM, so the `console.log()` statements [placed in the class] are also not printed into the console.

A simple Javascript class.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  sayHello() {
    console.log(`Hello, ${this.name}!`);
  }
}
```

Comment: *The problem is that the class itself does not get rendered into the DOM, so the console.log() statements [placed in the class] are also not printed into the console.* this isn't how console.log works. if `sayHello` gets called, the console log will print to the console, React is not at play here

Comment: have you tried `debugger` statement?

Comment: Rendering a component into the DOM is unrelated to console logging. I'm not sure where the cognitive disconnect is, but: React components are instantiated by **using** them, like in JSX; this happens because of how React/JSX work. POJSOs are instantiated "manually" by calling `new`, e.g., `const myClass1 = new MyClass('Jimmy Dean')`. In the snippet you provide calling `myClass1.sayHello()` would log to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when you call the function `sayHello` from an instance will the `console.log()` execute and you can see it inside the console. Right now you are not calling `sayHello` anywhere.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  sayHello() {
    console.log(`Hello, ${this.name}!`);
  }
}

const obj = new MyClass('Jimmy Dean');
obj.sayHello()
```